# Question about absolute convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is this series absolutely convergent?
$\sum (1/n)sin(n\pi /6)$.By Dirichlet test it is convergent.But how to conclude about absolutely convergent or not?

Comment: Knowing and applying the Dirichlet test here is a little less trivial than directly calculating $\sin(n\pi/6)$.

Comment: The sine values repeat periodically, so that you series can be absolutely bounded below by an Harmonic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Sigma|\frac{sin(\frac{n\pi}{6})}{n}| = sin(\frac{\pi}{6}) + sin(\frac{2\pi}{6})/2 + 1/3 + ... +1/9 +...+1/15+... \geq \Sigma_{i = 0}^\infty(\frac{1}{6i + 3})$ which is not convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Note $|\sin (n\pi/6)|= 1/2$ for $n=1,7,13,\dots ...$ Thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin (n\pi/6)|}{n} \ge \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{13} + \cdots\right)=\infty.$$

Comment: (+1) All to easy.